# Why is the $f(x)$ differentiable at $x=0$ but $f'(x)$ is not continuous near $0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Recently I saw a function from a book which states the function below is differentiable at $x=0$ but its derivative is not continuous at $x=0$.

```
Source was "Michael Spivak's Calculus 3E" pg.177
```

$$\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
      x²\sin\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg) \quad &\text{if} \, x ≠0 \\
      0 \quad &\text{if} \, x=0 \\
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}$$

So, accordingly;
$$\begin{equation*}
f'(x)=\begin{cases}
      2x\sin\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg)-\cos\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg) \quad &\text{if} \, x ≠0 \\
      0 \quad &\text{if} \, x=0 \\
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}$$

This shows $f'$ is not continuous at $x=0$. But I couldn't understand why is this happening. $f'(0)$ was the slope of line formed by points $(0,f(0))$ and $(h,f(h))$ where $h$ is infinitely small and was 0. Shouldn't it equal to slope of the line formed by $(h,f(h))$ and $(k,f(k))$ where $h<k<0$?

Could you explain me graphically why slope of line formed by $(0,f(0))$ and $(h,f(h))$ is $0$ while slope of line formed by $(h,f(h))$ and $(k,f(k))$ is $≠0$?

And can you please give me some more examples which is simpler than this? (A case where $f$ is differentiable at $a$ but $f'$ isn't continuous at $a$)

Comment: Did you graph $f'(x)$ to understand what is happening and why it is not continuous? Even though you have some control over how $ (0, f(0) ) \rightarrow (h, f(h) )$ looks like as $ h \rightarrow 0$, that doesn't mean that you have much control over how $( \epsilon, f(\epsilon) ) \rightarrow  ( \epsilon + h, f(\epsilon + h) ) $ looks like.

Comment: This *is* the simplest example of this phenomenon.

Comment: @TedShifrin dou you have another? Which doesn't involve trigonometric functions?

Comment: @CalvinLin graph seems unreadable there. But I think I understood why we doesn't have control over other sets of point.

Comment: Can you give me a non-trig bounded function on $\Bbb R$ with bounded derivative having no limit at infinity?

Comment: @TedShifrin  Do you mean there is no other example? (Non trig)

Comment: What is your antipathy toward basic trig? And did you answer my previous question?

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't have any antipathy toward trig but I'm desperate to know any other non trig function. And the answer to your question can be given by defining a piecewise function maybe.

Comment: Well, give me such a function and we’ll proceed.

Answer (score 3):

You say:

> $f′(0)$ was the slope of line formed by points $(0,f(0))$ and $(h,f(h))$ where h is infinitely small and was $0$. Shouldn't it equal to slope of the line formed by $(h,f(h))$ and $(k,f(k))$ where $h<k<0$?

I'm not quite sure what this means, but I suspect you mean that you'd like to take some kind of limit. The reason this doesn't work is because the limit you're suggesting we take does not exist.

As you asked for a geometric reason, I will try to explain this graphically. Here is the graph of the function $f(x)=x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right)$ near $x=0$:
[image: Graph of the given function very close to zero]
As you can see, the function oscillates forever towards zero from either direction. In doing this oscillation, its derivative varies between (just above) $1$ and (just below) $-1$ indefinitely. In doing this variation, the slope never approaches $0$. Note the difference between the following computations:
$$
f'(0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{h^2\sin\left(\frac1h\right)}{h}
= \lim_{h\to0}h\sin\left(\frac1h\right)=0
$$
$$
\lim_{x\to0} f'(x) = \lim_{x\to0}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(x+h)}{h} = \cdots
$$
This second one is not the same. Note the graph of $f'(x)$ looks like the following:
[image: the graph of the function's derivative]
It is often the case, especially in calculus, that you might ask "why are these two things not the same?" when the question you should be asking is "why should I believe that they would be the same?" This is one such example; there is no reason for the slope at a point to be the same as the limits of slopes around that point.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is directed to the question

> And can you please give me some more examples which is simpler than this? (A case where $f$ is differentiable at $a$ but $f'$ isn't continuous at $a$)

but rather than give you a concrete example I want to describe a process by which you could build as many examples as you like, that will hopefully also shed light on why the trigonometric example works.

Begin by choosing your favorite smooth function $E(x)$ with the following properties: $E(0) = 0$ and $E(x) > 0$ if $x \neq 0$.  Since $E$ is smooth and has its global minimum at $0$, we have $E'(0) = 0$.  (In the trig example, $E(x) = x^2$, which is surely the simplest possible choice.)  We're going to choose our function $f(x)$ so that $-E(x) \leq f(x) \leq E(x)$ for all $x$, which in the end is what's going to force $f'(0) = 0$.

Next, choose a decreasing sequence $a_1 > a_2 > a_3 > \ldots$ of positive real numbers with limit $0$ (these are going to be input values) and any sequence of real numbers $s_1, s_2, s_3, \ldots$ that does *not* approach $0$ (these are going to be slopes).  These sequences are going to witness $\lim_{x \to 0} f'(x) \neq 0$, as follows:

For each index $n$, choose a tiny distance $\epsilon$ (we'll say how tiny in a minute).  Now on the piece of the $x$-axis where $a_n - \epsilon < x < a_n + \epsilon$, draw a tiny segment of a smooth curve that passes through the point $(a_n, 0)$ and has slope $s_n$ at that point.  (You could make it a straight line segment if you wanted, for example.)  So now we can go back and say how small these little numbers $\epsilon$ have to be: small enough that the different intervals around $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots$ don't overlap, and small enough so that you can draw your steep curves without having them poke above the graph $y = E(x)$ or below the graph $y = -E(x)$.  (It is not completely trivial that you can always make such choices, but let's not get bogged down in details.  Also I guess let's not get fooled by my using a single symbol $\epsilon$: really it should be $\epsilon_n$, a different little radius around each point $(a_n, 0)$.)  (In the trig example, it's going to be $a_n = \frac{1}{n \cdot \pi}$ and $s_n = (-1)^n$.)

The little pieces from the last paragraph are going to be part of the graph $y = f(x)$.  To finish the graph, in the interlacing intervals, we draw a curve *however we want* so that the resulting thing is continuous, differentiable, and lives between the graphs $y = E(x)$ and $y = -E(x)$.  And then for negative $x$-values, just mirror the whole thing across the $y$ axis.

Now we check: *at $x = 0$*, by definition, the derivative of $f(x)$ is $f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h}$.  Since $-E(x) \leq f(x) \leq E(x)$ for all $x$, we have that $\frac{-E(h)}{h} \leq \frac{f(h)}{h} \leq \frac{E(h)}{h}$ for all $h > 0$ (and all inequalities reversed for $h < 0$).  Since $\frac{E(h)}{h} \to E'(0) = 0$ and likewise $\frac{-E(h)}{h} \to -E'(0) = 0$, we have by the squeeze theorem that $f'(0) = 0$.  However, *as $x$ approaches $0$*, we pass through each of the inputs $a_n$ in order, and at those inputs we have by construction that $f'(a_n) = s_n \not\to 0$, so $\lim_{h \to 0} f'(h) \neq 0$.